# Apache Freemarker - How to omit quotes in case of null values for a field in a json?

Tags: java, json, freemarker

I have a json template as below:

```
{
    "firstname": "${fname}"
}
```

When fname is null, I want to have the value as null instead of a string null ("null").
Hence, I'm expecting the final json to be like:

```
{
    "firstname": null
}
```

But, I'm getting:

```
{
    "firstname": "null"
}
```

Is there any way we can achieve this using Apache Freemarker? I'm pretty new to Freemarker and couldn't get a precise solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.32, it's just `"firstname": ${fname?cn}`. It's important that there are no quotes around the `${...}`! This works because if the left-side of `?c`/`?cn` is a string, now instead of failing, it quotes, and escapes it. (Thus you don't even have to know if the left-side is a number/boolean, which must not be quoted, or a string, which must be quoted, as it's automatic.) `?cn` is for "`?c` nullable", means, if the left-side is `null`/missing value, it prints a `null` literal (which of course won't be quoted), instead of failing like `?c` would. (Also check out the `c_format` setting for best results, but by default string formatting is JSON compatible, so using `?c`/`?cn` is an improvement without that too.)

**Old answer for 2.3.31**

You could use `#if` or `?then`, and then `??` operator to check if the value is `null`, but that's verbose. So instead, move the logic into a `#function` (or into a Java utility method that you expose):

```
<#macro nullMarker></#macro>
<#function jsonString s=nullMarker><#return s?is_macro?then('null', '"${s}"')></#function>
```

I had to do some ugly hack above, as for a function argument that's `null` there must be default value. So I can't simply use `s??` inside the function, as `s` inside the function will never be `null`. So instead, I specified a default value that you surely normally don't want to print as JSON. So now you can do this:

```
${jsonString(fname)}
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same by implementing the TemplateDirectiveModel interface in a Java code? I was reading about user defined directives but was not really able to retrieve the value of fname within the java code

Comment: With `TemplateDirectiveModel` or `TemplateMethodModelEx` the *value* of `fname` would be an argument, so you aren't retrieving the variable directly in their implementaitons. (Actually you can, but, that would be strange.) Also, if it should be similar to above, then it's `TemplateMethodModelEx`, not a directive.

Comment: @Bhanu Updated my answer, as in 2.3.32 there's a better/simpler solution for this.

Comment: @KrittamKothari FreeMarker 2.3.32 does support `?cn`. It's there in the linked page too; scroll up to the "Changes on the FTL side" section.